# Changing CRS units from meters to kilometers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have shape files with CRS of SWEREF99  with

```
+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

The units are all in meters  but I prefer to make a map with coordinates in kilometers. 
How can I define a new CRS based on the current one but with kilometers unit?

Comment: That would make Sweden in the existing shapefiles to appear 1.574 million km long. You have a wrong idea, make the application to present coordinates in different units and don't touch the CRS.

Comment: Then how? In QGIS composer manger I chose SWEREF99  as CRS but I in "Draw coordinates :Format"  there is no option for km scale and the coordinates are always in meters.

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing? Is is to make a printable map with print composer? An image about what you have now and a sketch about what you want to achieve would help a lot.

Comment: Yes. As you said I am trying to make printable map. I built a map with the mentioned CRS and defined grid for it. The Coordinates of this map which have been  displayed at the borders are in meters. I only want them to be displayed in km.

Comment: I believe that such feature is missing from QGIS. If you do not need to use your shapefiles together with other data you could try to rescale the data and make coordinate values smaller with v.transform by setting Y scale and X scale into 0.001.

Comment: I think this can be a good way for my purpose. But how I can define this v.transform? I am still a beginner and not aware of entire QGIS options.